Flutter project won't run in any emulator
I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zr4j6W7nmpg
and it was all doing fine until I messed up something in the ended that prevented the entire project to be displayed, these errors appear whenever i try to use "flutter run":
E/flutter ( 3098): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(146)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter ( 3098): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(487)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter ( 3098): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(686)] Could not launch engine with configuration.

Here is my github: https://github.com/WakaWakaEhe/music_player.git
And here are the .dart files I "think" i might have messed up
main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:music_player/components/my_drawer.dart';
import 'package:music_player/models/playlist_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:music_player/models/song.dart';
import 'package:music_player/pages/song_page.dart'; // Importing SongPage

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // get the playlist provider
  late final PlaylistProvider playlistProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //get the playlist provider
    playlistProvider = Provider.of<PlaylistProvider>(context, listen: false);
  }

  //go to a song
  void goToSong(int songIndex) {
    //update current song index
    playlistProvider.currentSongIndex = songIndex;

    //navigate to song page
    Navigator.push(
      context, 
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SongPage(),),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("P L A Y L I S T")),
      drawer: const MyDrawer(),
      body: Consumer<PlaylistProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
        // get the playlist
        final List<Song> playlist = value.playlist;

        // return list view UI
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: playlist.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              // get individual song
              final Song song = playlist[index];

              // return list tile UI
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(song.songName),
                subtitle: Text(song.artistName),
                leading: Image.asset(song.albumArtImagePath),
                onTap: () => goToSong(index),
              );
            });
      }),
    );
  }
}

song_page.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:music_player/components/neu_box.dart';
import 'package:music_player/models/playlist_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:music_player/services/audio_player_service.dart';

class SongPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SongPage({super.key});

  @override
  _SongPageState createState() => _SongPageState();
}

class _SongPageState extends State<SongPage> {
  final AudioPlayerService _audioPlayerService = AudioPlayerService();
  Duration _currentDuration = Duration.zero;
  Duration _totalDuration = Duration.zero;
  bool _isPlaying = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _audioPlayerService.onDurationChanged.listen((newDuration) {
      setState(() {
        _totalDuration = newDuration;
      });
    });

    _audioPlayerService.onPositionChanged.listen((newPosition) {
      setState(() {
        _currentDuration = newPosition;
      });
    });

    _audioPlayerService.setCompletionListener(_playNextSong);
  }

  void _playSong(String audioPath) async {
    await _audioPlayerService.stop();
    await _audioPlayerService.play(audioPath);
    setState(() {
      _isPlaying = true;
    });
  }

  void _pauseSong() async {
    await _audioPlayerService.pause();
    setState(() {
      _isPlaying = false;
    });
  }

  void _resumeSong() async {
    await _audioPlayerService.resume();
    setState(() {
      _isPlaying = true;
    });
  }

  void _playNextSong() {
    final playlistProvider =
        Provider.of<PlaylistProvider>(context, listen: false);
    playlistProvider.playNextSong();
    final nextSong =
        playlistProvider.playlist[playlistProvider.currentSongIndex ?? 0];
    _playSong(nextSong.audioPath);
  }

  void _playPreviousSong() {
    final playlistProvider =
        Provider.of<PlaylistProvider>(context, listen: false);
    playlistProvider.playPreviousSong();
    final previousSong =
        playlistProvider.playlist[playlistProvider.currentSongIndex ?? 0];
    _playSong(previousSong.audioPath);
  }

  String formatTime(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigitSeconds =
        duration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return "${duration.inMinutes}:$twoDigitSeconds";
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _audioPlayerService.stop();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<PlaylistProvider>(
      builder: (context, playlistProvider, child) {
        final playlist = playlistProvider.playlist;
        final currentSong = playlist[playlistProvider.currentSongIndex ?? 0];

        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25, bottom: 25),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  // App bar
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      // Back button
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      ),

                      // Title
                      const Text("P L A Y L I S T"),

                      // Menu button
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 25),

                  // Album artwork
                  NeuBox(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        // Image
                        ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          child: Image.asset(currentSong.albumArtImagePath),
                        ),

                        // Song and artist name
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              // Song and artist name
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    currentSong.songName,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(currentSong.artistName),
                                ],
                              ),

                              const Spacer(),

                              // Heart icon
                              const Icon(
                                Icons.favorite,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 25),

                  // Song duration progress
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            // Start time
                            Text(formatTime(_currentDuration)),

                            // Shuffle icon
                            const Icon(Icons.shuffle),

                            // Repeat icon
                            const Icon(Icons.repeat),

                            // End time
                            Text(formatTime(_totalDuration)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                      // Song duration progress slider
                      SliderTheme(
                        data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                          thumbShape: const RoundSliderThumbShape(
                              enabledThumbRadius: 8),
                        ),
                        child: Slider(
                          min: 0,
                          max: _totalDuration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                          value: _currentDuration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                          activeColor: Colors.green,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            _audioPlayerService
                                .seek(Duration(seconds: value.toInt()));
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),

                  // Playback controls
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      // Skip previous
                      Expanded(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: _playPreviousSong,
                          child: const NeuBox(
                            child: Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 20),

                      // Play/pause
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            if (_isPlaying) {
                              _pauseSong();
                            } else {
                              _resumeSong();
                            }
                          },
                          child: NeuBox(
                            child: Icon(
                              _isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      // Skip next
                      Expanded(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: _playNextSong,
                          child: const NeuBox(
                            child: Icon(Icons.skip_next),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

home_page.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:music_player/components/my_drawer.dart';
import 'package:music_player/models/playlist_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:music_player/models/song.dart';
import 'package:music_player/pages/song_page.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // get the playlist provider
  late final PlaylistProvider playlistProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //get the playlist provider
    playlistProvider = Provider.of<PlaylistProvider>(context, listen: false);
  }

  //go to a song
  void goToSong(int songIndex) {
    //update current song index
    playlistProvider.currentSongIndex = songIndex;

    //navigate to song page
    Navigator.push(
      context, 
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const SongPage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("P L A Y L I S T")),
      drawer: const MyDrawer(),
      body: Consumer<PlaylistProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
        // get the playlist
        final List<Song> playlist = value.playlist;

        // return list view UI
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: playlist.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              // get individual song
              final Song song = playlist[index];

              // return list tile UI
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(song.songName),
                subtitle: Text(song.artistName),
                leading: Image.asset(song.albumArtImagePath),
                onTap: () => goToSong(index),
              );
            });
      }),
    );
  }
}

I've tried flutter clean, adding the dependencies, edited some of the files that I might have messed up, but no errors appear in any of them and I'm already at least 36 hours no sleep and spent 10 hours coding this thing and frankly I've reached the pointed where I want to die and take this project along with me. Please help.

You're missing the main thread call and the initalization of the app.

Also you're missing the providers for your screens
